# Are there motherboards that support dual PSUs connections?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I was thinking about how I would build myself a server with redundant power supplies.

Now they sell redundant PSU units, but they are proprietary. If one PSU in the unit fails and you want to replace it you have to buy a replacement PSU that unit supports.

Do they make motherboards that have two PSU connections- the idea being you plug any two PSU into the motherboard and when one fails the mobo will intelligently switch over to the other.

I couldn't find any that do this which makes me think there is something inherently bad/unrealistic about this idea.

Comment: This is being flagged as off-topic as a hardware shopping recommendation. I don't agree; the question is whether ANY such motherboards exist, and I think that's a worthwhile question.

Comment: I think you will find that this is usually abstracted away from the motherboard itself. The motherboard had standard connectors that go to some sort of multiplexer and that has the two power supplies on it.

Comment: For example, [this](http://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9B-17-147-044&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleBiz-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleBiz-PC-_-pla-_-Server+Power+Supplies-_-9B-17-147-044&gclid=Cj0KEQjwy92wBRCl7trx4PaIo8EBEiQASPhtC1i82eSvLdUMheVZQKp2qdf1KJumDiPhhzQXb2Gt164aAoVa8P8HAQ)

Comment: Right as I said because its abstracted away from the motherboard you need to use PSUs compatible with that dual PSU carriage. That's why I was asking if there are motherboards that do this all on board. Do redundant PSU carriages conform to some standard? Can I use replacement PSUs for one carriage in a different one or are the always proprietary? The ones I have seen look proprietary.